# Greenfoot Can I create an actor instance in constructors?

Tags: java, greenfoot

I'm using the Greenfoot program to create a game, but cannot instantiate anything in a constructor. For some reason, nothing is made when I write `getWorld().addObject()` in the constructor.

I can create objects in the `act()` method, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Greenfoot only allows you to add objects from a world object, the other actors you are calling don't exist yet. This means there are no constructors to call `getworld()` on.